# custom wrap_content in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with ImageView on example 1. the width is fix-310dp and height is wrap_content. And when users load picture (e.g 1920x2560) in ImageView from their gallery it should be as an example 2. On which way to solve this problem?

[image: image view example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on your `ImageView`.

Update:

You need to set the scaleType to matrix and after that call setImageMatrix() with your matrix as a parameter.

```
mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
mImageView.setImageMatrix(myMatrix);
```

Comment: Thank thank you very much :)  and another thing to ask, how to do programmatically to fit image in imageView, to fit on imageView or start  and not stretched. Because i use android:scaleType="matrix"

Comment: I updated the answer to suggest a solution for your matrix usage.